# array of threads c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have this code:

```
    Thread[] threadsArray = new Thread[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            threadsArray[i] = new Thread(() => c1.k(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            threadsArray[i].Start();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            threadsArray[i].Join();
        }
```

the function k is this:

```
void k(int i)
{
    while(true)
      Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

for some reason just the last thread is running and printing 4444444....
why aren't all the threads running?

Comment: This has to be the most oddball variant of the standard closing-over-the-loop-variable question I've ever seen.

Comment: This one is even more similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930133/c-closures-why-is-the-loopvariable-captured-by-reference

Comment: Related: "Closing over the loop variable considered harmful" by Eric Lippert. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: i is a captured outer variable in this context. See http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_14.5.15.3.1_Captured_outer_variables

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All of the threads are printing the same variable.

Your lambda expression (`() => c1.k(i)`) captures the `i` variable by reference.
Therefore, when the lambda expression runs after `i++`, it picks up the new value of `i`.

To fix this, you need to declare a separate variable inside the loop so that each lambda gets its own variable, like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int localNum = i;
        threadsArray[i] = new Thread(() => c1.k(localNum));
    }
```

Comment: +1 for this answer. It's basically the same as Winston's, but the explanation is more detailed.

Comment: On a side note: some languages like F# won't compile if you try to capture a mutable variable in a closure.

Answer (score 4):

You are closing over the i variable.

Try this instead

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int x = i;
    threadsArray[i] = new Thread(() => c1.k(x));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread[] threadsArray = new Thread[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    //better use ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate
    threadsArray[i] = new Thread(k);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    //passing the value to the function
    threadsArray[i].Start(i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    threadsArray[i].Join();
}

//changing the input data type
void k(object i)
{
    while (true)
        Console.WriteLine((int)i);
}
```