# How to watch (i.e. debug) extra-lambda variable inside lambda scope in C#/Visual-Studio/Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lambda, visual-studio-2015, mono

When using Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Unity, I've noticed that when I am stepping though the body of a lambda expression, I cannot watch variables which were declared/assigned outside of but are being read inside of the lambda expression.

```
    private IEnumerator DoTheThing(string filter)
    {
        TextureDownload texDl = new TextureDownload();
        texDl.OnCompleted += () =>
        {
            _log.Log("Mesh texture " + texDl.GetType() + ":" + texDl.GetHashCode());
            textures.Add(texDl);
        };
        yield break;
    }
```

I get the error

> The identifier `texDl` is not in the scope

Obviously the variable is accessible in this scope, because the lambda function is using it.

Is there any remotely easy/convenient way to watch the value of such variables?

Comment: Maybe you should post a little more of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a variation of [C# lambda call in for loop references to last object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436227/c-sharp-lambda-call-in-for-loop-references-to-last-object)

There is an issue with Mono/Unity with coroutines and lambda expressions;

> The coroutine itself is an implicit closure as well which moves all local variable to a seperate class as member variables. That means it's impossible to create a "real" local variable inside a generator method. That's why the explicit local variable declaration doesn't work.

See http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/974036/c-lambda-call-in-for-loop-references-to-last-objec.html