# Receiving unexpected output while implementing multithreading in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to C# and multithreading concept and was exploring multithreading. I am getting unexpected output.
Following is the program I wrote in c#:-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {

        System.Threading.Thread workerThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => fn(i));
        workerThread.Start();

    }

    System.Console.WriteLine("!End the main process!");

}

public static void fn(int x)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"fn method called for {x}");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    for (int i = 1; i <=2 ; i++)
    {
        System.Console.Write($" {x} ");
    }
}
```

**Expected Output**:-
One of the expected output would have been:-

- !End the main process!
- fn method called for 1
- fn method called for 2
- fn method called for 3
- fn method called for 4
- fn method called for 5
- 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5

**Actual Output**
what I am getting is:-

- !End the main process!
- fn method called for 4
- fn method called for 3
- fn method called for 2
- fn method called for 5
- fn method called for 2
- 2  2  2  4  2  4  3  3  5  5

Why the function **fn** was called twice of **2** and why it wasn't called for **1**?

and when I re-run the function I am getting

- !End the main process!
- fn method called for 3
- fn method called for 4
- fn method called for 3
- fn method called for 6
- fn method called for 4
- 3  3  3  3  4  4  6  4  6  4

How did **fn** end up getting called for **6**?

Comment: Try `Thread workerThread = new Thread(fn); workerThread.Start(i);`, with `void fn(object x)` -- It's the lambda + closure you see at work. See, e.g., [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/271440/7444103) -- [C# Closures, why is the loopvariable captured by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1930133/7444103) -- [What is the exact definition of a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1095707/7444103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing `i` as an argument, it depends on what the value of `i` is at the specific moment the method is executed. If the method doesn't get executed until your loop has moved on to the next iteration, it will get the incremented value of `i`.

The solution is to not use a variable that has that outer scope. Declare a local variable specifically for the method argument:

```cs
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    var arg = i;

    System.Threading.Thread workerThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => fn(arg));
    workerThread.Start();    
}
```

`arg` is allocated anew for each iteration so every method call will get the correct value of `arg`.

Comment: If you use common terms like captured variables, this answer can be easier to understand. Articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions#capture-of-outer-variables-and-variable-scope-in-lambda-expressions and https://unicorn-dev.medium.com/how-to-capture-a-variable-in-c-and-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-d169aa161aa6 can be the references.