# .NET 8 Blazor - Why does razor render display after the for loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I'm guessing this is by design; if so, can someone explain why or how this happens? I read docs on Microsoft's website but found nothing explaining why a for loop behaves this way in a razor file.

When I FOR loop in the razor markup, the variable rendered is the final variable value and not the increment count. Why does it do that?

Markup...

```
<MudStack>

  @for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {

    <MudPaper>

      <MudText Typo="Typo.body1">
        @(x)
      </MudText>

    </MudPaper>
  }

</MudStack>
```

And the result...
[The result of the above markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8RmR.png)

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

I am expecting to see

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce a temporary variable:

```
<MudStack>

  @for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
    var tmp = x;
    <MudPaper>

      <MudText Typo="Typo.body1">
        @(tmp)
      </MudText>

    </MudPaper>
  }

</MudStack>
```

If I understand correctly the generated code will produce closure as with simple [lambda closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1930133/2501279) (I assume due to combination with MudBlazor)

> I am expecting to see .... 5

Then you will also need to change the loop condition to `i <= 5`

Comment: Ha - you posted just as I was writing my response. Thank you for confirming! I might have lost a few hairs over this tonight :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, for anyone experiencing this.. it's due to mudblazor and explained here: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/3970

[Example of how the fix works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY3co.png)